# Is the problem: $\underset{x}{\min}\|x-c\|_{2}^{2}$ subject to $Ax=b$ convex?

Tags: optimization, convex-analysis, convex-optimization, quadratic-programming

We define the problem:

$\underset{x}{\min} \|x-c\|_{2}^{2}$

subject to $Ax=b$.

First, I found the optimal solution

$$x^{\text{opt}}=c-A^{T}(AA^{T})^{-1}(Ac-b)$$

Next I want to find if this problem is convex or not. How I can do
this?

---

Edit: I know how to check the convexity of the objective function. I want to know how to verify if the convexity condition holds on the feasible area.

Comment: Do you understand the definition of a "convex problem"? If so, then which part of the definition are you having trouble with?

Comment: It is the most basic example of https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Second-order_cone_programming

Comment: @Omnomnomnom Yes, I just missed the part that is related to the feasible area. Mikal explained this well.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### Yes

First let's find the definition of an optimization problem being convex:

An optimization problem
$$
\begin{array}{rl} \underset{x}{\arg \min} &
f(x) \\ \text{subject to} & A x = b \end{array}
$$
is convex if the function $f$ is convex and the feasible region (defined by the constraint) is also convex.

Now. The quadratic objective is definitely convex
\begin{align}
f(\lambda x + (1-\lambda)y) &= \lVert \lambda x + (1-\lambda)y - c \rVert_2^2 \\
&= 
\lVert \lambda (x - c) + (1-\lambda)(y - c) \rVert_2^2 \\
&\leq
\lambda\lVert x-c\rVert_2^2 + (1-\lambda)\lVert y -c \rVert_2^2 \tag{triangle inequality} \\
&= \lambda f(x) + (1-\lambda)f(y).
\end{align}
The feasible set is defined by a linear constraint and therefore also convex. Suppose $$A x = b, A y = b$$
Then,
\begin{align}
A(\lambda x + (1-\lambda)y) &= \lambda A x + (1-\lambda) Ay \\
&= \lambda b + (1-\lambda)b \\
&= b
\end{align}
In other words, if $x$ and $y$ are inside the feasible region, so is the line between the two points. We have proved the two conditions of the definition and conclude that the problem is convex.